# Restoring Division Algorithm Implementation

Tags: java, algorithm

I'm trying to implement [Restoring Division](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Division_algorithm#Restoring_division) algorithm and things are going terribly wrong. Here is my code:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

    int num = 10;
    long den = 2;
    long p = num;
    int n = 32;
    den = den << n;
    StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder("");
    long q = 0;
    for(int i = n; n > 0; n--){

        p = (2 * p) - den;
        if(s.length() > 0){
            s.delete(0, s.length() - 1);                
        }
        s.append(Long.toString(q,2));

        if(p >= 0){
            s.setCharAt(i, '1');
        }else{  
            s.setCharAt(i, '0');
        }

        q = Integer.parseInt(s.toString(), 2);
    }
    System.out.println(q);
}
```

I'm getting `java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 32` exception. It's cause I'm trying to set a character(or a bit techincally) at a position that does not exist.

How do I implement this correctly? Can I get binary string with leading zeros?

Comment: You have five lines of same code in both branches of your if-statement. Put this before an after  the if-statement to make your code more readable.

Comment: Note that i starts with 32 and you decrement n in your loop. This seems not to be correct, because your string is empty at the beginning an you access the character at position 32.

Comment: Thanks for pointing out. I've refactored it.

Comment: Yes, I've already pointed that out in my question.

Comment: I mean you should think about your variables. You decrement n without using it, and leaves i constant. This makes no sense, although I do not know the desired algorithm.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's very odd that you would involve any `String`s in such a process.  You are working with binary arithmetic, so use integer data types and operators, especially bitwise operators (`&`, `|`, `^`, `<<`, `>>`, `>>>`).  Every integer data type implements a "binary string with leading zeros".  Especially so for this case, given the constraint of the restoring division algorithm that the inputs both be positive.

I'd probably write the central part more like this:

```
q = 0;
for(int i = 32; i > 0; i -= 1){
    q <<= 1;
    p = (2 * p) - den;

    if(p >= 0){
        q += 1;
    } else {
        // implicit: q += 0
        p += den;
    }
}
```

Note that it is bit 0 that is manipulated at every iteration.  The previous partial result (0 at the first iteration) is left-shifted by one to make room, and so that after all 32 iterations, each bit is in the correct position.